# set of points of $M$ the affix of $Z$

Tags: complex-numbers

let M be the affix of $Z$
 Determine the set of positions of $M$ the affix of $Z$ when the images of the numbers $1,Z$ and $Z^2+1$ are collinear.

I did $\arg((1-z)/(1-1-z²))=0$ then $\arg(1-z)-\arg(-z²)=0$ but I don't know how to complete and I tried in another way by saying $(1-z)/-z²=k$ where $k$ belong to Rand I solve the quatratic equation.

Comment: i did arg((1-z)/(1-1-z²))=0 then arg(1-z)-arg(-z²)=0 but i dont know how to complete
and i tried in another way by saying (1-z)/-z²=k where k belong to Rand i solve the quatratic equation

Answer (score 0):

Nopte the alignment of the images of $1, Z$ and $Z^2+1$ is equivalent, by translation to the algnment of the images of $0, Z-1$ and $Z^2$. This means  $\arg(Z-1)\equiv2\arg Z\mod \pi\mathbf Z$. Setting $\theta=\arg Z$, $r=\lvert Z\rvert$, this translates into:
$$\tan2\theta=\dfrac{r\sin\theta}{r\cos\theta-1}\iff (r\cos\theta-1)\sin2\theta= r\sin\theta\cos2\theta$$
Now use the duplication formulae:
\begin{align*}
2(r\cos\theta-1)\sin\theta\cos\theta&=r\sin\theta(2\cos^2\theta-1)\\
\iff r=2\cos\theta
\end{align*}
This is the polar equation of the circle of radius $1$ centred at the point with affix $1$.